# what does $options = get_option('test_theme'); do?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, theme-options

I'm trying to set up theme options so they save with AJAX, I found this tutorial http://return-true.com/2010/01/using-ajax-in-your-wordpress-theme-admin/

it's calling

```
$options = get_option('test_theme');
```

but I don't understand what that is returning. it calls this right before the form, presumably to loop through the options? the data is actually getting saved, it's just not being represented when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets $options to the value of test_theme in the database, you can go to phpmyadmin and the wp database and the wp_options (if wp is your prefix) and do a search on option_id row and you'll find it there.

To get this option it should be saved before in the database using [add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) and [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option), for more info check out the [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)